# Assistance with 'Procedure or function has too many arguments specified' error

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I need a second pair of eyes.  I'm getting that error in my C# code when I try calling the stored proc in question.

We're running SQL Server 2008 and here's my C# code and stored proc setup:

```
    SqlConnection oConn = null;
            string Name = "Frank";
            bool IsEmp = true;
            int RID = 31;

    oConn = SQLConnectionHelper.GetConnection(SQLConnectionHelper.OurDB);

    var sqlParams = new SqlParameter[3];
    sqlParams[0] = new SqlParameter("@RID", RID);
    sqlParams[1] = new SqlParameter("@Name", Name);
    sqlParams[2] = new SqlParameter("@IsEmp", IsEmp);

    SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(oConn, CommandType.StoredProcedure, "dbo.OurStoredProc", sqlParams);
```

Start of the stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[OurStoredProc]
(
    @RID            INT,    
    @Name           nvarchar(20),
    @IsEmp          BIT
)
As

BEGIN TRANSACTION
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: What does the `SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery` method look like?

Comment: @adrianbanks you ask a good question sir.  I don't have the source at hand but the signature is `ExecuteNonQuery(SqlConnection connection, CommandType commandType, string commandText, params SqlParameter[] commandParameters)`.
What I can say is when I have seen the source on other variations of that method, they're essentially pass-throughs to the Microsoft Data Access Application Block.  I apologize for not having more information on the method.

Comment: I am wondering whether the `SqlHelper` is not wiring the parameters up correctly. Either that or your stored procedure is not what you think it is - try running `sp_helptext OurStoredProc` to check what it is defined as.

Comment: I copied my stored procedure to a bare-bones equivalent (little more than the parameters shown in the code snippet above, followed by a 'print' statement) and that worked fine.  So I'm guessing something in the SP is the culprit here...I do return a 0 or 1 depending on error conditions.  But I changed my C# code to include a return parameter in sqlParams, and got the same error.  I'll keep trying, and will report back.

Comment: ..and the answer on this one appears to be operator error.  I had added three parameters to my stored proc in question (previously it had been two) and could _swear_ I had run `ALTER PROCEDURE` afterward to save the changes, but this morning I see that those changes did not take effect.